# Correct way to show a transformation is not isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose I have some transformation $T(f(t)) = \int_{0}^{t} f(x) dx$ from $P$ to $P$. I know this is a linear transformation, now my problem is that of proving it's isomorphic (or not, which in this case, I already know it's not).

I know that the dimensions of $P$ and $P$ are the same, so I would proceed with showing that the kernel of the transformation is $0$. I would go about doing this by showing that there is no function $f(t)$ in which the integral $\int_{0}^{t} f(x) dx = 0$, except for 0.

It's immediately obvious to me that it should be possible to create some function $f(t)$ that's negative from $0$ to $t/2$ and positive $t/2$ to $t$, or vice versa, thus showing that the kernel is not $0$. I think such a function would be $f(t) = sin(t)$, such that $T(f(2pi)) = \int_{0}^{2pi} sin(x) dx = 0$. 
Thus showing that $T(f(t))$ is not an isomorphism.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

EDIT: just realized that my approach doesn't even fall in $P$, that is to say $f(t) = sin(t)$ is not in $P$ (I think). I really don't know where to start with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For $f$ to be in the kernel, you'd need $Tf(x) = 0$ for all $x$, not just $2\pi$.  In fact, you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that the kernel of $T$ is $\{0\}$.  Instead, you should show that $T$ is not onto (Hint: what is $Tf(0)$?)

Comment: Could you elaborate on proving that the kernel is ${0}$? I've also just realized that $P$ is not finite dimensional, so I suspect that the proof falls into proving that the image of $T$ is $P$.  Is showing that $T$ is not onto equivalent to saying that image of $T$ has redundant vectors? I know that the definition of isomorphism is onto and one on one, I'm just struggling to relate it to vector spaces. So if $Tf(0) = 0$, and the kernel of $T$ is 0, it shows that it is not onto?